# Google Drive API Public download private account files

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api

I've been searching a while and I can't figure this out.

I need to know if it possible and how to create an web app to allow someone to download a certain file (introducing on First and Last Name) stored on a Google drive Account. The issue is that this files has to be private in Drive.

Is this possible? If it is based on PHP, Javascript or jQuery better.

I know that I need Google Drive API, but which certificates should I use?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Drive API uses OAuth2 for authorization. Most apps have the user go through the OAuth2 flow, so that app can access files in their Drive. If instead you want the users to download private files from your Drive, you can go through the OAuth2 flow once and then store the credentials so that they can be used for all users.

Comment: Got it! That's what I need, users to download private files from my Drive. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Erik, How do I store the credentials? In javascript or PHP. Iḿ googling and I can't find a clean answer

Comment: It depends on the client library you are using. You'll want to store the `refresh_token` in long-term storage, and the current `access_token` in short-term storage.

Comment: Please remember to upvote answers which you've accepted